# Swift - AdMob Rewarded Video - Can't Change Reward

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've implemented ADMob Rewarded videos in my app. Everything works well and videos can be seen. The problem is that the reward obtained is always the default one "10 coins". I have set my APP and Ad Unit IDs correctly but can not change my reward in relation to what I've entered in AdMob UI

Can someone help me?

My Code

In App Delegate

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-3400090518055344~XXXMYAPPXXX")
```

In My Controller

```
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID, "dea0b09d6ea6594ab92XXXMyDEVICEXXX" ]
rewardBasedVideo = GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance()
rewardBasedVideo.delegate = self
rewardBasedVideo.load(request, withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3400090518055344/XXXMYUNITIDXXX")
```

On click of a Button

```
if rewardBasedVideo.isReady == true {
    rewardBasedVideo.present(fromRootViewController: self)
}
```

In My Callback Func

```
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd,
                        didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
    print("Reward received with currency: \(reward.type), amount \(reward.amount).")
}
```

Screenshot

[Screenshot My ADMob UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgAnO.png)

[Screenshot xCode Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNT3f.png)

---

Comment: it will take some time to show your changes so wait for one hour and then check. also check whats other information you are getting in reward object

Comment: i'm waiting for 24 hours and nothing change

Comment: there are no other information inside reward object :(